# Convert decimal <-> hex

Tags: elisp

Given a list of decimal numbers, how can each number be converted to its equivalent hexadecimal value, and vice versa?

For example:

```
(convert2hex 255 64 64); -> (FF 40 40)
(convert2dec FF 40 40); -> (255 64 64)

(convert2hex 255 64 64 255 64 64 128)
(convert2dec FF 40 40 FF 40 40 80)
```

Comment: Is this homework?  What I would start by doing is understanding at a high level the algorithm for converting base ten to base sixteen, *before* trying to implement this in lisp.

Comment: Not homework.  Emacs Lisp probably isn't on any school's radar? :-) I would imagine that the actual conversion ability might be somewhere in Emacs.   If I just want a number converted, I can use Calc, for example.

Comment: I wrote lisp while i was in school.  Calling Calc seems like overkill, the base conversion algo is not that bad.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Number to Hex:

```
(format "%X" 255) ;; => "FF"
```

You can also zero-pad the value with:

```
(format "%03X" 255) ;; => "0FF"
```

Where the `0` is the character to use for padding and `3` is the number of spaces to pad.

Hex string to number

```
(string-to-number "FF" 16) ;; => 255
```

The `16` means "read as base-16."

Comment: argument `16` is called Radix.

Answer (score 18):

If you just want to type a hexadecimal number into Emacs, there's no need to call `string-to-number`, just use the `#x` reader syntax:

```
#xFF
==> 255
```

You can also use `#b` for binary, `#o` for octal numbers, or `#36r` for base 36:

```
#b10011001
==> 153
#o777
==> 511
#36rHELLO
==> 29234652
```

See [section 3.1 Integer Basics](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Integer-Basics.html#Integer-Basics) in the Emacs Lisp Manual

Answer (score 2):

I was interested in converting octal chars to hex chars in a source file.

I wanted to query search and replace on the following text:

```
'\0'   -> "\\0", // Null
'\7'   -> "\\a", // Bell (^G)
'\b'   -> "\\b", // Backspace (^H)
'\13'  -> "\\v", // Vertical tab (^K)
'\33'  -> "\\e", // Escape (^[)
```

Here was the regular expression search and replace

<kbd>C-M-%</kbd>

```
'\\\([0-9]+\)'
```

<kbd>RET</kbd>

```
'\,(format "\\0x%04X" (string-to-number \1 8))'
```

<kbd>RET</kbd>

The result is:

```
'\0x0000' -> "\\0", // Null
'\0x0007' -> "\\a", // Bell (^G)
'\b'      -> "\\b", // Backspace (^H)
'\0x000B' -> "\\v", // Vertical tab (^K)
'\0x001B' -> "\\e", // Escape (^[)
```